# Is this a valid MaxHeap structure?

Tags: java, tree, heap, min-heap, max-heap

I am trying to convert a minHeap class to a maxHeap class. I was given the code for the minHeap class, one method of which was add. It looks like this:

```
while (index > 1 && getParent(index).compareTo(newElement) > 0)
```

The first node is automatically set to null, so everything that gets add is placed in node 1 onwards. This code as already stated gives a minHeap structure. So change it to maxHeap, I simply flipped the comparator sign like so:

```
while (index > 1 && getParent(index).compareTo(newElement) < 0)
```

The items I am entering are being stored by an integer value. In order of insertion they are:

```
3
7
8
10
6
1
9
2
```

In the minHeap structure, these are stored in nodes like so:

```
            1
       2         3
    6     7   8     9
 10
```

In the maxHeap structure, changing the sign stores them like so:

```
           10
      8           9
   2     7     3     6
 1
```

Note how they are no longer in the same kind of sequential order as they were in the minHeap structure. Does this matter or is it still a valid maxHeap?

Apologies for my awful attempt at showing a tree like structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If your heap is being stored as you say it is a valid Max-Heap. A Max-Heap have the property that every node (except the root) contain a value that is less than or equal to its parent. Your heap obey this rule.

Comment: Thanks - I though it did, just wanted to be sure.